# How to fix JavaCC/jjTree error 'The code of method jjMoveNfa_0(int, int) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit'

Tags: parsing, generator, javacc

I'm writing a file parser using JavaCC/jjTree parser generator (https://javacc.org/)

Since the files to be parsed contain lots of data in a non-standard way (meaning: no CSV etc.) defining the grammar for the parser generator leads to lots and lots of TOKEN definitions.

At some point the automatically generated code for the "TokenManager" exceeds the limit of 65.535 bytes in the method "private int jjMoveNfa_0(int startState, int curPos)".

So my question is: how can one pass a parameter (or convince the JavaCC/jjTree code generator by any other means) to generate code, which does no break the limits?

Comment: Hey, did you found the solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. At least not the one I was hoping for. I'm trying to work around the problem by defining more methods in the grammar for structures instead of complex tokens, to reduce the number of required tokens. But at some point one reaches the limit again. I think it's an inherent problem of how JavaCC generates the code with constants for each token and a switch-case for each of them. So key problem in my opinion is, that one can only have a maximum number of tokens...

Comment: I understand I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Please post if you found any solution for it, I will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the the same problem. The reason was the definition of my tokens.
I had a lot of the following definitions:

```
< MY_TOKEN : "MY_TOKEN" | "TOKEN_VARIANT1" | "TOKEN_VARIANT2" | "TOKEN_VARIANT3" >
```

So I need to use in parser statement only

```
< MY_TOKEN >
```

**Solution:**

Split the definition into:

```
< MY_TOKEN : "MY_TOKEN">
| < TOKEN_VARIANT1 : "TOKEN_VARIANT1" >
| < TOKEN_VARIANT2 : "TOKEN_VARIANT2" >
| < TOKEN_VARIANT3 : "TOKEN_VARIANT3" >
```

Change parser definition into

```
< MY_TOKEN > | < TOKEN_VARIANT1 > | < TOKEN_VARIANT2 > | < TOKEN_VARIANT3>
```